# ExtJS 4 remoteSort asDate

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

For my remote-sort i use in ExtJS 3 the keyword *asDate* which was sent in direction-part of request:

```
sort:my_date
dir:asDate ASC
```

In ExtJS 4 i miss the sortType information in Request:

```
sort:[{"property":"my_date","direction":"DESC"}]
```

is there any way to get the sortType information on server side?

Comment: Most of the times, you know the type you are sorting already. Sorting is mostly done on database side. (It's made for it and it's best for it) in a database you can sort on a 'my_date' column the database knows it's a date if you save your dates appropriately. Same goes when you don't sort in the database but in the backend. The data in the store gets mapped to backend objects. If 'my_date' is saved in the appropriate data type it's easy to sort appropriately.

Comment: Yey, of course, but not in my case. I need to know which sortType is defined and if it is asDate, my backend convert it for the database to ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(...)

Comment: conclusion: your date is stored as string, not a date but you want to handle the string like it IS a date...

Comment: correct, because of our half relational and half document-oriented database structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can the override encodeSorters function. I'll make you an example :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/xLz5C/1/

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     sorters: [{
         property: 'age',
         direction: 'DESC',
         sortType: 'asDate'
     }, {
         property: 'firstName',
         direction: 'ASC'
     }],
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: '/echo/json/',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'users'
         },
         encodeSorters: function (sorters) {
             var min = [],
                 length = sorters.length,
                 i = 0;

             for (; i < length; i++) {
                 min[i] = {
                     property: sorters[i].property,
                     direction: sorters[i].direction,
                     sortType: sorters[i].sortType
                 };
             }
             return this.applyEncoding(min);

         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, changed a little bit to use sortType defined in fields, but works now.